# Twilight Imperium 2 Planetary Defence Units per planet question

Tags: twilight-imperium

So I was reading the rules for PDS units using the Deep Space Cannon technology and I want to be positive I understand it correctly. So if an enemy faction puts a control marker down and moves ships into a system within the range. I may fire one die per PDS unit in range?

There is a planet tile with three planets in it and you can have up to two PDS units per planet. So if that is the scenario, that would be six dice rolled in total? That seems really overpowered.

Comment: You've read the rules correctly - not sure what your question is?

Comment: This is pretty powerful early but once you can field some carries with fighters this won't be as powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's powerful, but remember that you're limited by the number of pieces you have.  And if I recall correctly, then you only get the 6 PDS units.  So while yes, the PDS wall is strong, it is just a Maginot line.  You can just go around it, since the PDS units have to be transported or rebuilt.

Comment: FYI, in 4ed PDS can't be transported.